# Bootstrap btn-default not lining up with input-group div elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="get">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" placeholder="domain" value="<?php echo $domain; ?>" name="domain" class="form-control" autofocus />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">DiG</button>
            <select class="btn btn-default" name="record_type">
            <option value="<?php echo $record_type ?>" selected><?php echo strtoupper($record_type) ?></option>
            <option value="soa">SOA</option>
            <option value="ns">NS</option>
            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="mx">MX</option>
            <option value="txt">TXT</option>
            <option value="cname">CNAME</option>
            <option value="srv">SRV</option>
        </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

My aim is for the button and drop-down to line up with the text box but instead the select menu is off like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVqcf.png

I've tried adding padding to the style but it just takes it out of line altogether.

How would I go about lining things up?

Comment: It lines up when I look at it in a fiddle which just has bootstrap applied so what other css have you got that might be affecting it? : https://jsfiddle.net/0hwf6e2x/

Comment: @LeoFarmer apologies, updated original question with more code. To clarify, it's wrapped in an input-group div.

Answer (score 0):

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/2wh9goc9/2/)

If you are meaning to lineup horizontal lines then look in this jsfiddle

Added style to select tag.

```
    <form action="" method="get">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" placeholder="domain" value="textvalue" name="domain" class="form-control" autofocus />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">DiG</button>
            <select class="btn btn-default" name="record_type" style="padding:7px 0;">
            <option value="selectedvalue" selected>Selected</option>
            <option value="soa">SOA</option>
            <option value="ns">NS</option>
            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="mx">MX</option>
            <option value="txt">TXT</option>
            <option value="cname">CNAME</option>
            <option value="srv">SRV</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```